# AngularJS - hello world

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am trying AngularJS out, but I found the official tutorial download code & pre-defined npm dependence without telling how to create it from beginning.

I am on linux (mint mate 17), with nodejs / npm / bower installed, but no more modules, now I want to make a hello world project, which has a index.html, it show "1+1=2" via:
`<p>1 + 1 = {{ 1 + 1 }}</p>`

I ask this question because I don't hope I can't even make a hello world from beginning by myself after finish the official tutorial, so don't laugh at me please, I did google, they are just similar as the official guider, I don't like that.

So, can anyone give me the simplest & least step-by-step guide, how to get angularjs, and run it?

Comment: You don't need node to use AngularJS. AngularJS runs in the browser. So you download the library from its web site (or using Bower), add a `<script>` tag in your HTML page referencing it, and use it like any other client-side JS library.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you! Got it, I was fooled by the complex official guide :)

Comment: FYI: Your request marked with bold letters won't stop us from moderating this site. It's not fun - it's responsibility. Ask good questions and nobody will try to close them. If you don't know yet, we have a __review queues__ here. It's not the case that we don't have time to answer. We __do__ find time to work with review queues. To make it clear - I'm not downvoting nor voting to close, because I think it's possible that other users can run into the same confusion.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo If it's really bad question, do your down vote or close, but you should know, different people with different background has different view/feeling on the same questions.

Comment: @flybird actually the value of your question is arguable in my opinion. The reason for your problem was trivial and such questions are generally discouraged here as they are usually not helpful for other users. Normally (like in your case) there was enough time to get the problem solved before the question was put on hold. So you did get your answer but the question will get deleted soon. As I said I think some other users may get confused just like you so I decided to take no other action but comment.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Yes, I I agree with you on that, I did get enough time to get my answer this time. I think they should give about 30 min before people kill questions that not valuable in their opinion. if in 30 min, no body want to give an answer, then kill it, no body care, even the asker. About my question, I believe it save time of people who not familar with nodejs/npm, and want to try angularJS out quickly. The problem is, not everyone is cautious enough, some people just"think" in their way, not in other people's situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is using **CDN** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>       
    <p> 1+2 = {{ 1+2 }}</p>     
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you can use `bower` to install `AngularJS`.

```
bower install angular#1.2.20
```

Comment: So simple, but thank you so much, now I understand its basic mechanism, the official guider is too bluffing, they should make your code the first step!